# Zebra RW420 is printing the ZPL commands

Tags: android, zebra-printers, zpl

I am trying to print images using `ZPL` commands to the `Zebra RW420` printer.
But the printer is printing the ZPL commands.
This behavior is observed whether I am sending the commands from my program or from the `Zebra Setup Utility`, and it is working fine on another `Zebra iMZ320` printer.
So I believe it is a configuration option, but I don't know what is the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out later.
The language of the printer wasn't set to ZPL so to fix it I used the following code:

```
BluetoothConnection connection = new BluetoothConnection(getMacAddress());
connection.open();
try {
    ZebraPrinter printer = ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance(PrinterLanguage.ZPL, connection);
    printer.sendCommand("! U1 setvar \"device.languages\" \"zpl\"");
} finally {
    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (ConnectionException ignored) {
    }
}
```

Or basically send the following ZPL command:
 `! U1 setvar "device.languages" "zpl"`